# Given the angles: θ,p and q,the value of the angle α is equal to:

Tags: geometry

in this exercise I only have a right angle, which is part of the isoceles triangle.

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yWZs.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that:
$$\theta+\angle{p}+\angle{BCA}=180°$$
So, this means that:
$$\angle{BCA}=180°-\theta-\angle{p}$$
Also, by the proprieties of triangles:
$$\angle{BCA}=90°+\alpha\leftrightarrow \alpha=90°-\theta-\angle{p}$$

Comment: @T-Rex: if this answer has been useful, maybe a $+1$ or a favourite answer?